# ObserverPattern, Platfrom.runLater() and ProgressBar: Not working properly when copying a large amount of files

Tags: java, javafx, progress-bar, observer-pattern

I've made a small MVC program which copies files from A to B. For better progress indication I use a `ProgressBar` and the `Observer Pattern` to refresh it.

Model (copier and Observable):

```
[...]
    Files.copy(file.toPath(), Paths.get(destinationPath.toString() + "/" + file.getName()),
        StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    copyingFile = file.getName();
    progress++;
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers("progress");
[...]
```

And the View (ProgressBar + Observer):

```
[...]
    progressBar = new ProgressBar();
[...]
    @Override
    public void update(Observable observable, Object arg) {
        if (observable != null && observable instanceof MainModel) {
            if (arg instanceof String && "progress".equals(arg)) {
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    progressBar.setProgress(model.getProgress());
                    copyingFile.setText(model.getCopyingFile());
                    percent.setText(df.format(progressBar.getProgress()* 100) + "%");
                });
         }
[...]
```

This works quite well. The `ProgressBar` is updated continuously but if I copy 100+ files (around 2MB) it doesn't work anymore.

It seems like either the `notifyObservers("progress")` triggers to often and gets stuck or something or the threads are too busy copying files that the JavaFX Thread which should update the `ProgressBar` gets no time doing it's job.

The whole problem made me think about the code and I got suspicious that this way of fast updating a `ProgressBar` - with the Observer Pattern - seems not to be a good way.

What's the proper way of updating a `ProgressBar`? Binding Properties?

Additional question:
I'm using the Observer Pattern to update all my data in the view. Because the model has to update a lot of different things and it doesn't always need to update the whole data I use this way of updating:

```
@Override
    public void update(Observable observable, Object arg) {
        if (observable != null && observable instanceof MainModel) {

        if (arg instanceof String && "progress".equals(arg)) {
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                progressBar.setProgress(model.getProgress());
                copyingFile.setText(model.getCopyingFile());
                percent.setText(df.format(progressBar.getProgress() * 100) + "%");

                if (progressBar.getProgress() > 0.5) {
                    percent.setTextFill(Color.WHITE);
                }

            });

        } else if (arg instanceof String && "finished".equals(arg)) {
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                progressBar.setProgress(1);
                copyingFile.setText("Fertig!");
                percent.setText("100%");
                finishButton.setDisable(false);
            });

        } else if (arg instanceof String && "events".equals(arg)) {

            eventChoiceBox.setDisable(false);
            List<String> events = new LinkedList<>();
            events.addAll(model.getEvents());
            Collections.sort(events);
            events.add(0, "Neue Veranstaltung...");
            eventChoiceBox.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(events));
            eventChoiceBox.getSelectionModel().select(model.getEvent());

        } else {

            userNames.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(model.getUsers()));
            filesList.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(model.getFilesAsString()));
            userNames.getSelectionModel().select(model.getUser());

        }
    }
```

I'm suspicious about this way with this whole `if-else` thing and the keywords (progress, finished, events).
Well, it works and use this way most times, but is this even a good way?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you be more specific than "it doesn't work anymore"?  What behavior are you seeing when you copy 100 or more files?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem is due to the value you pass to `progressBar.setProgress`.  The value needs to be between 0.0 and 1.0, but it looks like you might be passing the number of files copied.

There are many ways to implement the observer pattern which don't actually use the Observable and Observer classes.

JavaFX, in particular, uses observable, bindable properties.  Your `progress` variable can be replaced with a [Task](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html), whose observable progressProperty can be bound to your ProgressBar's value.  It can also be bound to the percentage indicator, and the task's message property can be bound to the current file indicator:

```
Task<?> copyTask = new Task<Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Void call()
    throws IOException {
        int progress = 0;
        for (File file : files) {
            Files.copy(file.toPath(), Paths.get(destinationPath.toString(), file.getName()),
                StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            updateMessage(file.getName());
            updateProgress(++progress, files.size());
        }
        return null;
    }
};

ReadOnlyDoubleProperty taskProgress = copyTask.progressProperty();

progressBar.progressProperty().bind(taskProgress);
finishButton.disableProperty().bind(taskProgress.lessThan(1.0));
percent.textProperty().bind(
    taskProgress.multiply(100).asString("%.0f%%"));

Paint defaultColor = new Label().getTextFill();
Paint halfDoneColor = Color.WHITE;
percent.textFillProperty().bind(
    Bindings.when(taskProgress.greaterThan(0.5)).then(halfDoneColor).otherwise(defaultColor));

copyingFile.textProperty().bind(copyTask.messageProperty());

new Thread(copyTask).start();
```